# Error: Directives must appear before any declarations. Try moving the directive before any declarations. import '../url_launcher_string.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

Need help. I can't run my app because of this issue.
[image]

I have reinstalled and tried as much but I can't run......
if I try to run on android, it says the `JDK` path is invalid and shows.
and if I try to run on Chrome, it shows the following error (in Fig)
Here is the code for the url_Launcher page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ukhan_tukka/utls/custom_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:ukhan_tukka/utls/drawer.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
class PrivacyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
const PrivacyScreen({super.key});
Future<void> _launchURL(url) async {
if (!await launchUrl(
url,
mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
)) {
{
throw "Could not launch $url";
}
}
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
drawer: Drawerpage(),
body: SafeArea(
child: Column(
children: [
CustomAppBar(),
SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4),
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlkkm.png)
height: 50,
width: 120,
child: Center(
child: GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
_launchURL("https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences");
},
child: const Text('About Us')),
),
),
],
),
),
);
}
}`
```

when i clone the project and try to run it shows above issues

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. Somehow, in the developing process pub cache become 'dirty'. My errors for the web were:

```
: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations. 
 http.dart: Try moving the directive before any declarations.
 import 'dart:convert';...
```

or for iOS:

```
Error (Xcode): ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-1.1.0/lib/http.dart:8:1: Error: Directives must appear before any declarations.
```

The solution for me was to clear pub caches. Commands:

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

And reinstall pubs:

```
flutter pub get
```

Maybe you will need to add the command:

```
flutter clean
```